# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(e^{\frac 1 n}-1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} n(e^{\frac 1 n}-1)$

This should be solved without LHR. I tried to substitute $n=1/k$ but still get indeterminant form like $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to 0} \frac {e^k-1} k$. Is there a way to solve it without LHR nor Taylor or integrals ?

Maybe with the definition of a limit ?

EDIT:

$f(x)'=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)(e^{1/x+h}-1)-x(e^{\frac 1 x}-1)}{h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{xe^{1/x+h}+he^{1/x+h}-x-h-xe^{\frac 1 x}+x}{h}=
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{xe^{1/x+h}+he^{1/x+h}-h-xe^{\frac 1 x}}{h}$

Comment: It should be $\frac{e^k-1}{k}$. Which definition of $e^x$ are you working with?

Comment: Write it as ${e^{1/n}-e^0\over 1/n}$ and try to recognize the limit as a derivative.

Comment: @DanielFischer right, fixed. I think we learned all the definitions of it.

Comment: So write $$e^x = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m!},$$ compute $n(e^{1/n}-1)$ from it, and take the limit.

Comment: @DanielFischer but that's Taylor and I'm not supposed to use it here...

Comment: @GinKin No, that's the **definition** of $e^x$ I use. That it is coincidentally the Taylor series of $e^x$ about $0$, well, who cares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why should one use Taylor where we don't need it at all?

$$L = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left(e^\frac{1}{n}-1\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

Substitute $u=e^x-1$. Then $x=\ln(u+1)$

$$L=\lim\limits_{u \to 0}\frac{u}{\ln(1+u)}=\lim\limits_{u\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{u}\ln(1+u)}=\lim\limits_{u\to0} \frac{1}{\ln \left ( 1+u\right)^{1/u}}=\frac{\lim\limits_{u\to0} 1}{\lim\limits_{v \to \infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{v}\right)^v}=\frac{1}{\ln e}=1$$

Comment: Very neat! Nice job.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{e^\frac{1}{n}-e^0}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{k\to0}\dfrac{e^k-e^0}{k}$. Use the definition of a differential.

Comment: You mean $f(x)'=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ ? I tried it now and it didn't work...

Comment: @GinKin What did you try?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: @GinKin Interpret as follows: $$e^k=e^{k+0}$$ You'll get it now.

Comment: But if I substitute h with 0 I still get 0/0...

Comment: @GinKin You get the derivative of $e^x$ evaluated at $k=0$, i.e., $1$.

Comment: If I substitute h with 0 here $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{xe^{1/x+h}+he^{1/x+h}-h-xe^{\frac 1 x}}{h}$ I get 0/0, I must have made a mistake or didn't use the definition correctly, can you please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: @GinKin As I said, it's the derivative of $e^x$ evaluated at $0$, i.e., $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x = \frac{1}{n}$

The limit becomes $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} \rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1+x-1}{x} = 1$

using the Maclaurin series for $e^x$

EDIT: Just noticed you also excluded Taylor series (which would preclude Maclaurin's) in your question. So feel free to ignore my answer.

Comment: No Taylor.${}{}$

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. Jumped right in after the first line which said "without LHR", so I assumed Maclaurin's/Taylor's was OK. Then I read the rest. :)

Comment: It is OK since even without Taylor one can prove that $e^x - 1\sim x$ as $x\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

Again this turns out to be a very nice question. Without making any assumptions on $e$ or $e^{x}$ it is possible to show that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}n(e^{1/n} - 1)$ exists. To be more general we can show that for any real number $x > 0$ the limit $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1)$$ exists. We need to deal with cases $0 < x < 1$, $x = 1$ and $x > 1$ and to it can be seen that the case $0 < x < 1$ can be handled via the case $x > 1$ if we put $x = 1/y$. For $x = 1$ the limit is obviously $0$.

For $x > 1$ we need to show that the sequence $g(x, n) = n(x^{1/n} - 1)$ decreases as $n$ increases and obvious $g(x, n) > 0$ so that the limit $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1)$ exists.

As a next step we can show that the limit function $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$ for $x > 0$ and satisfies $$f(1) = 0, f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$$ and with some more effort we can show that $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = 1/x$ so that $f(x)$ has all the properties of $\log x$ or $\ln x$.

If we define $e$ as a number such that $\log e = 1$ then obviously we get $\lim_{n \to \infty}n(e^{1/n} - 1) = 1$. This approach towards the definition of logarithm via limits is presented in detail in [my blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html).

Comment: Do you use multi variable calculus here ?

Comment: No its all single variable calculus. see my blog post linked in the answer.